# unicode error when decoding

Tags: python, django, unicode, byte

I use configparser to read a configuration I do like this :

```
file = b'[OWNER]\r\naction=PRODUCT_SENDS_CONFIG\r\nimei=861311003801742\r\nphone_number=0616055459\r\nSN=100004\r\nproduct_name=TACT\r\nproduct_version=01.00\r\n[DATABASE]\r\nstring=\xc4a\xc4a\xc4a\xc4a\r\n'

config = configparser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.readfp(StringIO(stream.read().decode(encoding='utf-8')))
```

However I get this error :

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 462: invalid continuation byte**

Do you how what can be the solution, I don't know the treatments to do on the file variable before using configparser, I'd like to read \xc4a as Ä ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need a different encoding set such as `iso-8859-1` perhaps, otherwise:

```
>>> b"\xc4a\xc4a\xc4a".decode(encoding='utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte ...
```

Let's try using `iso-8859-1` instead:

```
>>> b"\xc4a\xc4a\xc4a".decode(encoding='iso-8859-1')
u'\xc4a\xc4a\xc4a'
...
>>> print("\xc4a\xc4a\xc4a".decode(encoding='iso-8859-1'))
ÄaÄaÄa
```

It looks like `iso-8859-1` was the correct encoding.

Sometimes adding the encoding being used in a special comment at the top of your script can be useful for Unicode literals too:

```
>>> #!/usr/bin/env python
... # -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
... 
>>> u = u'abcdé'
>>> print ord(u[-1])
233
```

↳ https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I put ISO format to resolve it.

However I have another problem now, I have to send back hexadecimal data like the one I received previously : \xc4a\xc4a\xc4a in a string.

I made an hex data and appended it to my config string like this, I transformed each char of a string to its decimal value and finally applied hex on it :

```
checksum = 0 
for c in str_config: 
    b = int(hex(ord(c)), 16) 
    checksum += b 
return str_config+hex(checksum)
```

But the result display the hex like this :  '0xb2a5' and not as \xb2a5

Do you know how I can resolve this ?